# How exactly does a generic view like DeleteView make your app more scaleable in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

My app is currently built exclusively on function-based views, and I'm looking into class based views and especially the generic ones to make it more scaleable - as this is recommended many places.

For the class based views in general, I can see the utility as opposed to hundreds of function based views. However - I'm having trouble seeing how the generic ones do anything to save time. I'm trying to figure out the DeleteView now, and it seems to be actually adding more complexity to my code.

Currently, a deletion view for me looks like this:

```
views.py

def fruit_delete(request, num):
    fruit = fruits.objects.filter(pk=num)
    fruit.delete()
    return redirect(fruits)
```

And all I need to add is a path:

```
urls.py

path('fruit_delete/<int:num>', views.fruit_delete, name='fruit_delete'),
```

And a easily replicated button in my templates:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href = "{% url 'fruit_delete' fruit.pk %}"
           onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this fruit?')">Delete</a>
```

And this does the job. If I was to need a hundred or so of those views however, it would be beneficial to be able to use the model in question, or other parameters, as arguments in the template itself instead of having to create a separate view + path for every single one. However, this doesn't seem to be the case, as every example I see requires the model to be declared in the class.

So how - exactly - does a generic view like DeleteView enable scaleability?

Comment: I have been in the same situation that you are my friend. What I figured is that the generic views do help for simpler applications for a person who is quite well versed with Django already. They help in reducing your application development time, because you need to type less code (if you already know Django Generic Views very well, else you waste time going through the docs) and your code is cleaner and there is less code to maintain. 

I dont think there is much more to it than this.

Comment: If you want to use one single view for deleting from multiple types of models, you can dynamically attach that model and then do the deletion process too. 

Generic views don't help you much here, apart from the points I told above.